# iOS 9 Beta 5- Calendar Privacy Access Alert not showing up on iPhone but is showing up on simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, calendar, watchkit

With the new iOS 9 Beta 5 and watch os 2 firmwares, I have encountered something very odd.

I am trying to use this code, which is supposed to bring up an alert asking for permission to access the calendar, if the user hasn't already granted access. The problem is that the alert never comes up even when user hasn't given access to the calendar:

```
if ([store respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAccessToEntityType:completion:)])
{
    NSLog(@"Monkey");
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
    {
         NSLog(@"Banana");
         /*
         more code here
         */
    }
}
```

After adding breakpoints to the code I have deduced that this line is the issue:

```
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
```

Anything after this line will never execute, so the alert never shows up. However, the same line works if I run the watchkit App on the simulator instead of my own watch and iPhone. Although I have an if-else statement for `granted`, the statement won't execute because anything after the `{` won't execute. Meaning that the log will not show `Banana`, only `Monkey`. This happening when testing it on my own device. On the simulator both will show and the access to calendar alert will also come up.

Also to note, this same code ran perfectly fine on my own devices and simulator when iOS 9 Beta 3 was released. When I updated my phone to iOS 9 Beta 5 about a week ago, I was having this problem, so I have reason to believe that it might be a bug of some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Apparently I forgot to do a software update on my apple watch. Updating the watch makes the privacy alert show up and now I can grab calendar events on the watch.

Comment: Mine is not showing in Simulator and device. My project is converted to Xcode 7. I am not using Apple Watch. Do you have any idea why is this?